# Arrow body disappearing in tikz graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, tikz-arrows, tikz-graphs

I used Tikz library `graphs` to draw a graph, that is:

```
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
```

Here's my code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph  {
     "$x_1$" -> {
        "$x_2$" -> "$x_3$",
        "$x_4$" -> "$x_5,x_8$" 
     } -> "$x_6,x_7$"
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However the arrow body miraculously disappeared:

[image]

How can I deal with it?

Comment: When I compile the code in the context of a minimal document I get a short arrow. It is shorter than the other arrows in the diagram, but it does not consist of only the arrowhead. Can you please combine the snippets into a full example document with `\documentclass` a preamble and `\begin{document}...\end{document}` that reproduces the issue (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). An MWE makes sure that we are all talking about the same thing. It might also help if you could upload your `.log` file to a text-sharing website like https://pastebin.com/

Comment: In addition to @moewe's comment you can just increase the distance between the nodes, try e.g. `\begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph[grow right=2cm]  {
     "$x_1$" -> {
        "$x_2$" -> "$x_3$",
        "$x_4$" -> "$x_5,x_8$" 
     } -> "$x_6,x_7$"
    };
\end{tikzpicture}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always increase the distances between the nodes. In the current graph this can be achieved by adjusting the `grow right` key.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {1,1.1,...,2,1.9,1.8,...,1.1}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (-0.3,0.3) rectangle (6.6,-1.4); % only for the animation
    \graph[grow right=\X cm]  
    {
     "$x_1$" -> {
        "$x_2$" -> "$x_3$",
        "$x_4$" -> "${x_5,x_8}$" 
     } -> "${x_6,x_7}$"
    };
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow it very nice...a spring code :-). Very very good.