# Tikz does not show the bodies of arrows even though there is enough space

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-arrows, overleaf, plot

Hell, im trying to create a plot with some arrows like the one shown below.
[image]

The code I wrote to create it is the one below:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, tick style={very thick},xlabel={x}, ylabel={loss},]
        %
        %line of best fit
        \addplot[yscale=0.7,ultra thick,samples=151,domain=0:10] {0.3*(x-5)^(2) + 1};
    \end{axis}
    \node[scale=2, red] (1) at (0.43,3) {\textbullet};
    \node[scale=2, red] (2) at (0.55,2.7) {\textbullet};
    \node[scale=2, red] (3) at (0.71,2.4) {\textbullet};
    \node[scale=2, red] (4) at (0.87,2.1) {\textbullet};
    \node[scale=2, red] (5) at (1.05,1.8) {\textbullet};
    \node[scale=2, red] (6) at (1.27,1.5) {\textbullet};
    
    \node[transparent] (6) at (0.15,3) {\textbullet};
    \node[transparent] (7) at (0.3,2.7) {\textbullet};
    \node[transparent] (8) at (0.51,2.4) {\textbullet};
    \node[transparent] (9) at (0.67,2.1) {\textbullet};
    \node[transparent] (10) at (0.9,1.8) {\textbullet};
    \node[transparent] (11) at (1.2,1.5) {\textbullet};

    \draw [<-] (6) -- (7);
    \draw [<-] (7) -- (8);
    \draw [<-] (8) -- (9);
    \draw [<-] (9) -- (10);
    \draw [<-] (10) -- (11);
    \newline
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Following the same logic, I wrote the code below to create a similar plot but with the dots being at somewhat different places:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, tick style={very thick},xlabel={x}, ylabel={loss},]
        %
        %line of best fit
        \addplot[yscale=0.7,ultra thick,samples=151,domain=0:10] {0.3*(x-5)^(2) + 1};
    \end{axis}
    \node[scale=2, red] (1) at (0.43,3) {\textbullet};
    \node[scale=2, red] (2) at (0.64,2.5) {\textbullet};
    \node[scale=2, red] (3) at (0.9,2) {\textbullet};
    \node[scale=2, red] (4) at (1.25,1.5) {\textbullet};
    \node[scale=2, red] (5) at (1.61,1) {\textbullet};
    \node[scale=2, red] (6) at (2.1,0.5) {\textbullet};

    \node[transparent] (60) at (0.1,3) {\textbullet};
    \node[transparent] (70) at (0.3,2.5) {\textbullet};
    \node[transparent] (80) at (0.6,2) {\textbullet};
    \node[transparent] (90) at (1,1.5) {\textbullet};
    \node[transparent] (100) at (1.4,1) {\textbullet};
    \node[transparent] (110) at (1.85,0.5) {\textbullet};

    \draw [->] (60) -- (70);
    \draw [->] (70) -- (80);
    \draw [->] (80) -- (90);
    \draw [->] (90) -- (100);
    \draw [->] (100) -- (110);
    \newline
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However the image produced is the one you can see here, basically the bodies of the arrows are not shown, even though there is enough space (Mind you the previous image has even less space and the bodies still show). The idea is exactly the same and the code is almost identical if it wasnt for the coordinate changes. Do you have any ideas why that would be and how to solve it ?

This is what I get:

[image]

I have checked posts like these but they have not been helpful as the issue there is different:

- [How can one change the arrow shaft thickness globally in a TikZ picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600867/how-can-one-change-the-arrow-shaft-thickness-globally-in-a-tikz-picture)
- [Arrow body disappearing in tikz graph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492667/arrow-body-disappearing-in-tikz-graph)

Comment: Possibly you have redefined somewhere the arrow (or its default `line width` has been set to zero). On overleaf your code (with the basic preamble) works as expected.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @koleygr I havent messed with the arrow settings and the two code pieces are one below the other so nothing could change between them.

Comment: Thank you @Mensch

Comment: @wwatzy: Your code produces the arrows correctly when I compile it with only `pgfplots` and `\documentclass{article}`. Please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands and ends with `\end{document}` that reproduces your result.

Comment: I just moved the dots away from each other and reduced their scale and the arrows appeared. Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP solved it himself.